# How does Lastpass autofill work in Android?

Tags: android

Apparently since Android 4.3, Lastpass is able to autofill in password fields in browsers and other apps. How are they doing this? I am curious because I want to implement a tool that detects images that are currently on the screen. If Lastpass is able to detect password fields, then it might be possible for my requirement. However, I am a complete novice when it comes to Android.

Answer (score 1):

LastPass appears to be using an "Accessibility Service"

> Accessibility services can take action on behalf of users to make
>   interacting with applications simpler and more productive. The ability
>   of accessibility services to perform actions was added in Android 4.0
>   (API Level 14) and significantly expanded with Android 4.1 (API Level
>   16).

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html#act-for-users

You can follow the documentation for acting on behalf of users or look at the [ClockBackService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/accessibility/ClockBackService.java) or [TaskBackService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/accessibility/TaskBackService.java) sample apps. LastPass is most likely using something like `AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE` to autofill onscreen editText fields.